# splits y modifcacion de texto en Netbeans JAVA

Tags: java, archivo

Estoy haciendo un programa en JAVA que abre un archivo de texto y edita unos renglones en el archivo es de este tipo:

```
PreUtterance=  
Intensity=100  
Modulation=0  
PBW=333,286,411,525,471.2  
PBS=0  
PBY=0,125.1,-19.3,69.9,
```

Necesito editar el segundo y cuarto valor del renglon PBW y multiplicarlo por 2. Es decir, 286 y 525 multiplicarlos por 2 y dejarlos así:

```
PBW=333,572,411,1050,471.2
```

Ya tengo como abrir el archivo con una interfaz y así pero quiero saber como identificar el renglon con `"PBW=..."` y editarlo de esa manera.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes trabajar con el método **[contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))** para detectar la línea que quieres modificar.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
if (linea.contains("PBW=333")){
    ...
}
```

Con **[split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))** trozeas la **línea** guardándolo en un array de String

```
String[] trozos = linea.split(",\\s*"); //cogeremos posición 1 y 3
```

Hacemos la modificación de la línea en los trozos respectivos

```
trozos[1] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(trozos[1]) * 2);
trozos[3] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(trozos[3]) * 2);
```

Guardamos la línea en un String volviendo a poner las comas con todo modificado, utilizando el método **[join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...))** y lo guardamos en un `StringBuilder`

```
String str = String.join(",", trozos);
builder.append(str).append("\r\n");
```

---

Te dejo el código al completo..

```
public class ModificarArchivo {
    static StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        leerFichero();
        escribirEnFichero();
    }

    public static void leerFichero(){
        try (BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("archivos/fichero1.txt"))) {
            String linea = br.readLine();
            while(linea != null){
                if (linea.contains("PBW=333")){
                    String[] trozos = linea.split(",\\s*"); //cogeremos posición 1 y 3

                    trozos[1] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(trozos[1]) * 2);
                    trozos[3] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(trozos[3]) * 2);

                    String str = String.join(",", trozos);

                    builder.append(str).append("\r\n");
                    linea = br.readLine();
                }
                builder.append(linea).append("\r\n");
                linea = br.readLine();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error en el flujo de lectura");
        }
    }

    public static void escribirEnFichero(){
        try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("archivos/fichero1.txt"))){
            bw.write(builder.toString());
            bw.flush();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ModificarArchivo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

---

**Y el resultado del mismo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]